# Toggle a bunch of divs also changing the link

Tags: jquery, html, text, toggle, visibility

I have a bunch of divs, identified with an ID starting with a string (kind = "brand").
I want to toggle the visibility of the divs by clicking an href inside an span. I want the text of this link to change from "SHOW" to "HIDE".

Without the change of text, the function is just onle line:

```
  jQuery("#" + kind + "-" + value).toggle();
```

but with the text I cannot by add one line after other, til almost 15 lines of code. Surely it is much simpler than that.

**Updated code**

```
            function show_hide(brand, value){
                var show_hide_text = ["SHOW", "HIDE"];
                var id_selected = jQuery("#" + brand + "-" + value).attr("id");
                jQuery('div[id ^= "' + brand + '"]').each(function() {
                    if(this.id != id_selected){
                        jQuery(this).hide();
                        jQuery("#" + this.id.replace("-", "-show-")).html(show_hide_text[0]);
                    }else{
                        var visi = (jQuery("#" + brand + "-show-" + value).html() == show_hide_text[0]) ? 1 : 0;
                        jQuery("#" + brand + "-show-" + value).html(show_hide_text[visi]);
                    } // if
                });
                jQuery("#" + brand + "-" + value).toggle();
            } // function
```

The HTML code would go like this (just one div shown):

```
    <div ><h3 >SUPER BRAND <a href="javascript: void(0);" onClick="hide_show('brand', 'Super-brand');"><span id=brand-show-Super-brand">SHOW</a></span></h3>
      <div class="brand" id="brand-Super-brand">
            <div>PRODUCT #1</div>
       </div>
  </div>

    <div ><h3 >MEGA BRAND <a href="javascript: void(0);" onClick="hide_show('brand', 'Mega-brand');"><span id=brand-show-Mega-brand">SHOW</a></span></h3>
        <div class="brand" id="brand-Mega-brand">
          <div>PRODUCT #3</div>
        </div>
     </div>

...
```

Comment: Could you provide examaple html code?

Comment: HTML added to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if i understand you correctly, but here's code. HTML is also changed a little.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var show_hide_text = ["SHOW", "HIDE"];
  $('.show-hide-content').hide();
  $('.show-hide-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $content = $(this).parent().next('.show-hide-content');
    $('.show-hide-content').not($content).hide().prev().children('a').text(show_hide_text[0]);
    $content.toggle(); // Toggle visible
    $(this).text(show_hide_text[+$content.is(':visible')]); // Change text
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>StackOverflow Testing Page</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h3>SUPER BRAND <a href="#" id="brand-show-Mega-brand" class="show-hide-toggle">SHOW</a></h3>
      <div class="brand show-hide-content" id="brand-Super-brand">
        <div>PRODUCT #1</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h3>MEGA BRAND <a href="#" id="brand-show-Mega-brand" class="show-hide-toggle">SHOW</a></h3>
      <div class="brand show-hide-content" id="brand-Mega-brand">
        <div>PRODUCT #3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is that when you click one brand, the other div has to toggle too, with its :visible set to false, and also the text must change, from "HIDE" to "SHOW". If you click one brand and then the other you will see. I have reduced my code to 11 lines instead of your 7, but still see too much code.

Comment: So if you click one brand, you want to open all divs with the same brand?  or you want to open just that one brand, and hide every else?

Comment: Exactly, the last behaviour. I update the code above to what I have, which is the minimum I have been able to achieve.

Comment: My code is updated. Try now. Remember also that, you can't look at length of the code only, but also at it's quality and clarity.

Comment: That's the correct behaviour. The code is ways much clearer than mine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class to your LINK so you know if it is being shown or not. Also, you can use the "Starts With" from Jquery to [identify objects that start with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$("#YourLinkID").click(function(kind,value){

    //  Your previous code.
    //
    if($(this).hasClass("show"))
    {
        if($(this).html("Your HTML for Hide Link"));
        $(this).removeClass("show");
    }
    else
    {
        if($(this).html("Your HTML for Show Link"));
    }

    }
});
```

Haven't had a chance to test the code but you get the idea from it. If you still need it, please let me know and I'll try to make it a working example.

Comment: The problem is when you click a different link, it should toggle all the other divs. I have reduced to 10 lines of code, but still have to get the visibility. I will publish if I find a better solution, I thought about your approach of removing or adding classes, but it is only the text which is affected so may seem somehow unnecessary to reach that level. Thanks for the startwith tip, it is very useful.